# Changing the global scope in JS

Tags: javascript, iframe, window

Say i have an `Iframe` running inside of a parent window.

I have a single script loaded inside the `Iframe` and I want that script to have access to the variables inside of its parent.

Rather than saying `window.parent.X` all the time, is it possible to just declare:

```
window= window.parent;
```

inside of the `Iframe`?

Comment: Setting the global identifier _window_ won't work. You can create a closure that shadows it or you can use a different identifier, e.g. `var pwind = window.parent`

Comment: @PaulS. can you give an example of what you mean by "create a closure that shadows it" I'm relatively new to JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window` is a protected variable for js, you will not be able to override it. You can, however, store `window.parent` in another var and then use that:

```
var parentWindow = window.parent;
```

Answer (score 1):

> can you give an example of what you mean by "create a closure that shadows it"

```
// `window` here works normally

(function (window) {
    // `window` here is what would be `window.parent`
}(window.parent));

// `window` here works normally
```

Please note that even inside the *IIFE*'s closure you still have the same global object, i.e. anything you don't access via `window` will not be from the parent window.